# Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Professional error ...please reinstall the application

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Problem:

Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Professional closes shortly after opening the application/program.

```
Error:

"An error has been detected with a required application library and the product cannot continue. Please reinstall the application."
```

Attempts to remedy:

1. Followed suggested course of action within the error message 'Please reinstall the application.' I uninstalled completely and reinstalled the program.
2. Ran virus and malware scans on my pc and made sure no malware or viruses exist.
3. Googled the error message and found nothing helpful in serps
4. Posted issue in two forums thus far without any solutions offered to this point; 
   Adobe Community Forum, and Fixya.com Forum
5. Searched "SuperUser" Questions that may already have my answer and found nothing that would hlep.

History:

Have had this program running on my system for over three years without a glitch whatsoever and it just now began giving me this error message each time I attempt to open it.

I believe that it may be malware related as my pc was recently infected with a couple of regenerating bugs. "Snap.do" and "Default Tab" malware bugs.

It acts like a vital portion of the program is being blocked from execution or has maybe  been corrupted.

Looking forward to receiving a detailed solution to this problem.

Comment: I have repeatedly removed malware. I can install AA 5.0 Pro and open it without any problems. It is just AA 7.0 Pro that I am having this problem with. Also, I just installed a trial version of Adobe Acrobat XI and can open it without issues. 

My AA 7.0 Pro install disc has never been tampered with and this problem just began happening for no obvious reason.

If I posted a more detailed log...can you determine more from that?

Thank you,

Comment: Hello Ramhound, your assistance in this matter is no longer needed. I have exhausted the matter. And I did give enough info for someone else to assist me. Thank you for taking the time to tell me I needed to provide more info. Others have offered solutions to my issue and I think it best for me to stay with the Adobe Acrobat community rather than with non-specialists in this collection of experts such as yourself.

Comment: I guarantee you that others didn't provide solutions based on only the information contained in this question.  Of course its your choice to dismiss somebody who can help you.